# Eslinter not detecting Defined prop-types for react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, eslint, react-proptypes

In Created a javascript file with the following code:

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from "react"
import PropTypes from  "prop-types"

export default class DefaultBootstrap extends Component {
  render() { return (<div>Hi</div>) }
}

DefaultBootstrap.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}
```

When I run `npm start` it shows the following linter error:

```
xxx/xxx/index.js
  1:1  warning  Definition for rule 'prop-types' was not found  prop-types
```

So My question is why it is showing me the above warning even when i have defined the prop-types rules on it?

I used Webpack, Babel, React and Eslinter to setup up my application.

.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": ["react"],
  "rules": {
    "prop-types": ["warn"],
  }
}
```

[package.json (Click To See Complete File)](https://gist.github.com/mabdullah353/f5f6eb4395a9eca38c328f38c1d5c058)

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.1.2",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "eslint": "5.6.1",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.11.1",
    "webpack": "4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node": "^10.11.0",
    "prop-types": "15.6.2",
    "react": "16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "16.5.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.3",
  }
}
```

[webpack.config.js (Click here To See Complete File)](https://gist.github.com/mabdullah353/fdde2c9364d4ece95e171315791eeeba)

```
    rules: [
        {
          test: /\.m?js$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
        },
```

Answer (score 3):

Before it gets to looking at your code, ESLint is first looking for the implementation of the `prop-types` rule. The error message is saying that it can't find that rule. Since the `prop-types` rule is provided by a plugin, `eslint-plugin-react`, and is not one of the built-in rules, you'll need to prefix its name in your `.eslintrc.json` with the plugin name and a slash: `react/prop-types`. This tells ESLint that it should look for the `prop-types` rule inside `eslint-plugin-react`.

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": ["react"],
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": ["warn"],
  }
}
```

You can read more in the [rule configuration docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#using-configuration-files).